# Is there a C/C++ function to safely handle division by zero?

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point, divide-by-zero

We have a situation we want to do a sort of weighted average of two values **w1** & **w2**, based on how far two other values **v1** & **v2** are away from zero... for example:

- If **v1** is zero, it doesn't get weighted at all so we return **w2**
- If **v2** is zero, it doesn't get weighted at all so we return **w1**
- If both values are equally far from zero, we do a mean average and return (**w1** + **w2** )/2

I've inherited code like:

```
float calcWeightedAverage(v1,v2,w1,w2)
{
  v1=fabs(v1);
  v2=fabs(v2);
  return (v1/(v1+v2))*w1 + (v2/(v1+v2)*w2);
}
```

*For a bit of background, v1 & v2 represent how far two different knobs are turned, the weighting of their individual resultant effects only depends how **much** they are turned, not in which direction.*

Clearly, this has a problem when `v1==v2==0`, since we end up with `return (0/0)*w1 + (0/0)*w2` and you can't *do* `0/0`. Putting a special test in for `v1==v2==0` sounds horrible mathematically, even if it wasn't bad practice with floating-point numbers.

So I wondered if

- there was a standard library function to handle this
- there's a neater mathematical representation

Comment: `v1==v2==0` sounds horrible programatically too - it will not do what some might assume it should :-)

Comment: That wasn't intended as code, but a logical condition that both are zero. Sorry for confusion...

Comment: @John, that's what I assumed - just couldn't resist commenting :-)

Comment: @John: The tests for `0.0` are actually mathematically defensible, because the mathematical function `F(x, y) = x / (x + y)` is discontinuous at `x = 0, y = 0`.  So you have to special case that point - in this case, you're replacing it by the limit as `x` and `y` both approach 0 (which, luckily, is defined and finite).

Comment: @caf: the limit as (x,y) approaches (0,0) along the trajectory (r,r), r approaching 0. This pathwise limit exists, but the discontinuity at (0,0) is not removable.

Comment: @R: Ahh, yes - quite so, there *is* no defensible value to use for `x = 0, y = 0`.

Answer (score 14):

You're trying to implement this mathematical function:

```
F(x, y) = (W1 * |x| + W2 * |y|) / (|x| + |y|)
```

This function is discontinuous at the point `x = 0, y = 0`.  Unfortunately, as R. stated in a comment, the discontinuity is not removable - there *is* no sensible value to use at this point.

This is because the "sensible value" changes depending on the path you take to get to `x = 0, y = 0`.  For example, consider following the path `F(0, r)` from `r = R1` to `r = 0` (this is equivalent to having the X knob at zero, and smoothly adjusting the Y knob down from R1 to 0).  The value of `F(x, y)` will be constant at `W2` until you get to the discontinuity.

Now consider following `F(r, 0)` (keeping the Y knob at zero and adjusting the X knob smoothly down to zero) - the output will be constant at `W1` until you get to the discontinuity.

Now consider following `F(r, r)` (keeping both knobs at the same value, and adjusting them down simulatneously to zero).  The output here will be constant at `W1 + W2 / 2` until you go to the discontinuity.

This implies that *any* value between `W1` and `W2` is equally valid as the output at `x = 0, y = 0`.  There's no sensible way to choose between them.  (And further, always choosing 0 as the output is completely wrong - the output is otherwise bounded to be on the interval `W1..W2` (ie, for any path you approach the discontinuity along, the limit of `F()` is always within that interval), and 0 might not even lie in this interval!)

---

You can "fix" the problem by adjusting the function slightly - add a constant (eg `1.0`) to both `v1` and `v2` after the `fabs()`.  This will make it so that the minimum contribution of each knob can't be zero - just "close to zero" (the constant defines how close).

It may be tempting to define this constant as "a very small number", but that will just cause the output to change wildly as the knobs are manipulated close to their zero points, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: Actually, that will cause the output to change less when either weight is near zero.  The output is incredibly sensitive when there is no small constant being added.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What I mean is, if the constant is `1e-7` and `v1` is 0, then changing `v2` from `2e-7` to `1e-7` will change the output from `0.25 * w1 + 0.75 * w2` to `0.33 * w1 + 0.66 * w2`.  Obviously, a constant of 0 is worst of all.

Comment: +1 for the effort of explaining first year mathematical analysis in the context of programming.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best I could come up with quickly

```
float calcWeightedAverage(float v1,float v2,float w1,float w2)
{
    float a1 = 0.0;
    float a2 = 0.0;

    if (v1 != 0)
    { 
        a1 = v1/(v1+v2) * w1;
    }

    if (v2 != 0)
    { 
        a2 = v2/(v1+v2) * w2;
    }

    return a1 + a2;
}
```

Comment: Both your and Mike's solution involve an explicit equality check on a floating point number for zero, is that a)unavoidable b)bad? Or do the asymptotes cancel out regardless how close to zero we get?

Comment: @John: If the divisor is not exactly 0 then the divide operation should succeed. Right?

Comment: no, it shoudn't.  What is 145.0 divided by 1e-7?  Remember, it's got to fit inside of a float.  It'll be a numerical overflow.

Comment: @wheaties: Eh? 145/1e-7 = 1.45e9 which is quite expressible as a float. Three are cases where BIG/small will overflow a float however. But in this case v1/(v1+v2) is bounded from above by 1, and w1 is expressible as a float, so you're good.

Comment: This just hides the problem - using `0` as the output when `v1 == v2 == 0` is not right (if 0 does not lie in the range `w1..w2` then it's not the limit of the function along *any* path to the discontinuity).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see what would be wrong with just doing this:

```
float calcWeightedAverage( float v1, float v2, float w1, float w2 ) {
    static const float eps = FLT_MIN; //Or some other suitably small value.
    v1 = fabs( v1 );
    v2 = fabs( v2 );

    if( v1 + v2 < eps )
        return (w1+w2)/2.0f;
    else
        return (v1/(v1+v2))*w1 + (v2/(v1+v2)*w2);
}
```

Sure, no "fancy" stuff to figure out your division, but why make it harder than it has to be?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't see anything wrong with an explicit check for divide by zero. We all do them, so it could be argued that *not having it* is uglier.

However, **it is possible to turn off the IEEE divide by zero exceptions**. How you do this depends on your platform. I know on windows it has to be done process-wide, so you can inadvertantly mess with other threads (and they with you) by doing it if you aren't careful.

However, **if you do that your result value will be `NaN`, not 0**. I highly dooubt that's what you want. If you are going to have to put a special check in there anyway with different logic when you get NaN, you might as well just check for 0 in the denominator up front.

Answer (score 1):

So with a weighted average, you *need* to look at the special case where both are zero.  In that case you want to treat it as 0.5 * w1 + 0.5 * w2, right?   How about this?

```
float calcWeightedAverage(float v1,float v2,float w1,float w2)
{
  v1=fabs(v1);
  v2=fabs(v2);
  if (v1 == v2) {
    v1 = 0.5;
  } else {
    v1 = v1 / (v1 + v2); // v1 is between 0 and 1
  }
  v2 = 1 - v1; // avoid addition and division because they should add to 1      

  return v1 * w1 + v2 * w2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You chould test for `fabs(v1)+fabs(v2)==0` (this seems to be the fastest given that you've already computed them), and return whatever value makes sense in this case (`w1+w2/2`?). Otherwise, keep the code as-is.

However, I suspect the algorithm itself is broken if `v1==v2==0` is possible. This kind of numerical instability when the knobs are "near 0" hardly seems desirable.

If the behavior actually is right and you want to avoid special-cases, you could add the minimum positive floating point value of the given type to `v1` and `v2` after taking their absolute values. (Note that `DBL_MIN` and friends are not the correct value because they're the minimum *normalized* values; you need the minimum of all positive values, including subnormals.) This will have no effect unless they're already extremely small; the additions will just yield `v1` and `v2` in the usual case.

Comment: -0.5 (rounded up) So: `fabs(v1) + fabs(v2) == 0` tests whether `v1` and `v2` are equally far from zero? I may be very wrong ... english is my 2nd (3rd actually) language ... but there's something fishy around here somewhere

Comment: It tests whether they're both 0, with a single conditional. If either is nonzero, the existing code "works" (in a strange sense of works..).

Comment: It's not strange. If v1 and v2 are equally far from zero, their absolute values are the same and (v1/(v1+v2)) == (v2/(v1+v2)) == 1/2

Comment: Read the comments about the discontinuity of the function below the OP. That's what I mean by strange.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using an explicit check for zero is that you can end up with discontinuities in behaviour unless you are careful as outlined in cafs response ( and if its in the core of your algorithm the if can be expensive - but dont care about that until you measure...)

I tend to use something that just smooths out the weighting near zero instead.

```
float calcWeightedAverage(v1,v2,w1,w2)
{
  eps = 1e-7; // Or whatever you like...
  v1=fabs(v1)+eps;
  v2=fabs(v2)+eps;
  return (v1/(v1+v2))*w1 + (v2/(v1+v2)*w2);
}
```

Your function is now smooth, with no asymptotes or division by zero, and so long as one of v1 or v2 is above 1e-7 by a significant amount it will be indistinguishable from a "real" weighted average.

Answer (score 0):

If the denominator is zero, how do you want it to default? You can do something like this:

```
static inline float divide_default(float numerator, float denominator, float default) {
    return (denominator == 0) ? default : (numerator / denominator);
}

float calcWeightedAverage(v1, v2, w1, w2)
{
  v1 = fabs(v1);
  v2 = fabs(v2);
  return w1 * divide_default(v1, v1 + v2, 0.0) + w2 * divide_default(v2, v1 + v2, 0.0);
}
```

Note that the function definition and use of static inline should really let the compiler know that it can inline.

Comment: default is a mean average ( **w1** + **w2** )/2, since **v1** and **v2** are equally far from 0

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#include <float.h>

float calcWeightedAverage(v1,v2,w1,w2)
{
  v1=fabs(v1);
  v2=fabs(v2);
  return (v1/(v1+v2+FLT_EPSILON))*w1 + (v2/(v1+v2+FLT_EPSILON)*w2);
}
```

edit:
I saw there may be problems with some precision so instead of using FLT_EPSILON use DBL_EPSILON for accurate results (I guess you will return a float value).

Comment: Do you know what `FLT_EPSILON` is or did you just pick it because it has epsilon in its name?

Answer (score -2):

I'd do like this:

```
float calcWeightedAverage(double v1, double v2, double w1, double w2)
{
  v1 = fabs(v1);
  v2 = fabs(v2);
  /* if both values are equally far from 0 */
  if (fabs(v1 - v2) < 0.000000001) return (w1 + w2) / 2;
  return (v1*w1 + v2*w2) / (v1 + v2);
}
```

Comment: You can't catch floating-point exceptions in a portable fashion.

Comment: -1 for ridiculous epsilon antics in place of proper analysis.

Comment: @R. the 0.000000001 may be pushing it; but what would a proper analysis be?